# How do I find an element colour; the element I need to check changes colour when toggled

Tags: c#, css, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I need to identify two colours from an element when it is toggled on and toggled off; for example when its On its rgb(40, 170, 228) and when toggled Off rgb(101, 113, 151). I am using Iwebdriver, so limited with the methods that this brings to the table.

I have tried to not success `string colour = IWebElement.GetCssValue("background-color");` from another question, however, due to GetCSSValue not being present then I get an error

> iWebdriver Does Not Contain A Definition For GetCssValue

Comment: is in manually you can see the back-ground clour, if yes then wait issue

Comment: I can physically see the colour change, so thats not the issue. The issue is not having the code to identify the colours.

Answer (score 0):

The following works -
Add the following to your POM:

```
public IWebElement BranchToggleOn { get { return driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/thead/tr/th[3]/div/label/span")); } }
```

Then in your test:

```
string attValue = HomePage.BranchToggleOn.GetCssValue("rgb 255, 255, 255");
```